# How to read the registry values and compare it?

Tags: c#, registry

I have created a desktop application using WPF C# and in my application it will ask for product key to every user who installs the application so my requirement is the username and product key i'm storing in the registry by doing the following code now, when my user once he enters product key then it is saving in registry from there when ever user opens the new instance of the application, my application should check for the credentials in the registry if they were present it should open normally if the credentials are not available in the registry then a popup window should come and ask for the product key.

```
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey exampleRegistryKey = 
    Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("ExampleTest");
exampleRegistryKey.SetValue("UserName", textBox1.Text);
exampleRegistryKey.SetValue("ProductKey",textBox2.Text);
exampleRegistryKey.Close();
```

I have created the dialog box for my product key information all the things how to read the registry values to my application.

Comment: How did not googling "registry getvalue" come into your mind?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Registry.GetValue(keyName,valueName, defaultValue)`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.getvalue.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have a look:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3389/Read-write-and-delete-from-registry-with-C

*There are several Registry examples.*

***You may also have a look at MSDN for your basic knowledge***

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/Microsoft.Win32.Registry%28v=vs.110%29.aspx